# Is it possible to have dual monitors using a virtual terminal?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-terminal

I'm a bit of a command line nuthead.

I have a computer with dual monitors. Its setup works just fine in X11 - dual monitors, where my desktop stretches all the way across.

However, what I would like is to replicate that behavior when I'm using the virtual terminal. Right now, it simply mirrors the output.

Is there any way to have my resolution streeeeetch all the way across both monitors? e.g. instead of 80x24, I'd have 160x24?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I reread your question. In TTY without X, no. You can set a default boot connection mapped to a tty session, but without a separate session w/ keyboard map (such as serial/kbd and attached monitor/kbd) I don't know of a way to split that out and to be able to switch between the two.

Consensus is that the console itself without X, it maps into a default tty session attached to a primary default device. That default device is mapped to default input devices. Theoretically, you could map devices to separate tty sessions, but the single kbd would still map to the primary device mapping. Sort of like me remembering the old-school separate debug monitor output for Borland C in DOS. The second monitor ended up as separate display, but you had no real interaction with it.

As for creating a virtual terminal and picking apart that session to diplay across two separate monitors... Not able to do that without some type of framebuffer (graphic's like X).

In real-world practice, I believe the answer is "No."

Comment: Any tips for, say running tty1 and tt2 on different monitors, and switching the keyboard from one to the other?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get two ttys on two monitors by mapping them to corresponding frame buffers using Kernel parameters. You can even have background refresh by using fb terminal instead of the default tty (Getty in most cases)

Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556782/tty-dual-monitors for more clues.